# Pandas to recognize current date, and filter a date column relative to today's date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Having a lot of trouble translating the logic below in pandas/python, so I do not even have sample code or a df to work with :x

I run a daily report, that essentially filters for data from Monday thru the day before what 'Today' is. I have a Date column [ in dt.strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y') format] . It will never be longer than a Monday-Sunday scope.

1) Recognize the day it is 'today' when running the report, and recognize what day the closet Monday prior was. Filter the "Date" Column for the Monday-day before today's date [ in dt.strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y') format ]

2) Once the df is filtered for that, take this group of rows that have dates in the logic above, have it check for dates in a new column "Date2". If any dates are before the Monday Date, in Date2, change all of those earlier dates in 'Date2' to the Monday date it the 'Date' column.

3) If 'Today' is a Monday, then filter the scope from the Prior Monday through - Sunday in the "Date" Column. While this is filtered, do the step above [step 2] but also, for any dates in the "Date2" column that are Saturday and Sunday Dates - changes those to the Friday date.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here're the steps:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())

day_of_week = today.dayofweek

last_monday = today - pd.to_timedelta(day_of_week, unit='d') 

# if today is Monday, we need to step back another week
if day_of_week == 0:
    last_monday -= pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')

# filter for last Monday
last_monday_flags = (df.Date == last_mon)

# filter for Date2 < last Monday
date2_flags = (df.Date2 < last_monday)

# update where both flags are true
flags = last_monday_flags & date2_flags
df.loc[flags, 'Date2'] = last_monday

# if today is Monday
if day_of_week == 0: 
    last_sunday = last_monday + pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')
    last_sat = last_sunday - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')

    last_week_flags = (df.Date >= last_monday) & (df.Date <= next_sunday)

    last_sat_flags = (df.Date2 == last_sat)
    last_sun_flags = (df.Date2 == last_sun)

    # I'm just too lazy and not sure how Sat and Sun relates to Fri
    # but i guess just subtract 1 day or 2 depending on which day
    ...
```

Comment: As well, could you help describe what to do for this situation- second step of bullet point 2: Filter the "Date" Column for the Monday-day before today's date [ in dt.strftime('%#m/%#d/%Y') format ]

Comment: You need to review your data as you said in the post: `I have a Date column`, while the error says you don't.

Comment: You are correct, sorry on my oversight @ quang Hoang

Comment: # filter for last Monday
last_monday_flags = (df.Date == last_monday) -- In this line I see you are filtering the DF by whatever Date was last monday,  but here I would also want to filer for whatever day's are inbetween last monday and prior to today - so if Today was Thursday, it would filter the "Date" Column for the date of Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday (To add more to my questions above)

Comment: It didn't say so in your question. Nevertheless, `last_monday_flags = (df.Date >= last_monday) & (df.Date <= today)`

Comment: I made updates to the code and have encountered more errors, if you could be so kind to provide input again, I am getting close!

Comment: `last_monday_flags` is indeed a Boolean series. You would get a dataframe by `df[last_monday_flags]` or `df.loc[last_monday_flags,:]`, which you can see later in the code.

Comment: did my other steps look sound (changing column format and changing last_monday to .date() ??

Comment: Yes, for your purpose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699698/pandas-typeerror-cannot-compare-type-timestamp-with-type-date

Comment: so I have mad a lot of progress with your help, the code I have put back original comments (Under 'As of 4.17'), takes the df, filters for Completed Date Range , and then adjusts the Due Date appropriately. The the thing is I need to now just need to input those new Due Dates to replace what those Due Dates used to be in the Original DF (Essentially a vlookup, that only takes in values that are NEW) so I am trying this here :     finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date']), 'Due_Date'] = finaldfmon['Due_Date'] #- this threw errors
...... but I an error

Comment: I looked online, at what people say is that it is because when you do print(len(finaldfmon.index)) , the lenghts are different, but the thing is I do not know why that would cause an erorr and how to fix it

Comment: You’d better post it as a separate question and update all the code and errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736206/pandas-df-loc-can-only-compare-identically-labelled-series @Quang Hoang