# Pandas - df.loc - Can Only Compare Identically-labelled Series

Tags: python, pandas

My code below ( sorry I cannot share exact data) takes a df, filters it by date ranges, and re-labels certain date. I want to then pull those re-labeled dates into the original df. It works fine until this line of code:

```
finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date']), 'Due_Date'] = finaldfmon['Due_Date']
```

From now own research, it is because the index length is not the same.

```
print(finaldf.index)
```

vs

```
print(finaldfmon.index)
```

I do not get why this would be an issue nor do I know how to solve it. I want to simulate an excel vlookup, but would not leave an #NA if their was not hit ( as in the Anchor value (think primary key) did not have any matches (foreign key).

Full code here:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import xlrd # added when using visual studio 
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime
    finaldf = pd.read_excel("scrubcomplete.xlsx", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype=object)
    finaldf.columns = finaldf.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
    #
    today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())
    day_of_week = today.dayofweek
    last_monday = today - pd.to_timedelta(day_of_week, unit='d') 
    finaldf = finaldf[finaldf.Affliate_Code.str.contains('Part/Unix', na=False)]

f day_of_week !=0:
    finaldf['Completed_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Completed_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date
    finaldf['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Due_Date'], format="%m/%d/%y").dt.date # making it lower case y made it work 
    current_week_flags = (finaldf.Completed_Date >= last_monday.date()) & (finaldf.Completed_Date <= today.date()) # this worked as of 4.16
    earlydue = (finaldf.Due_Date < last_monday.date())
    flags = current_week_flags & earlydue
    finaldfmon = finaldf[current_week_flags]
    finaldfmon.loc[(finaldfmon['Due_Date']<last_monday.date()), 'Due_Date'] = last_monday # here we make all the due dates before monday, monday while complete date filterered
    finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date']), 'Due_Date'] = 
    finaldfmon['Due_Date'] 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('currentweek.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    finaldf.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
    writer.save()
```

The Error is:

```
  raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

It is caused by:

```
finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date']), 'Due_Date'] = finaldfmon['Due_Date']
```

Comment: Don’t create `finaldfmon`. Update the flags, similar to what you did with `flags = current_week_flags & earlydue`.

Comment: updating the flags will create a boolean, I need to overide the old Due Dates in the original df, with the new due dates that were created off of grouping the COmpleted Date and Due Date columns. That is what is going on through my head when I read your response. I thank you  for it, but I am confused

Comment: I am almost thinking now it may be easier to have conditonal logic using .loc . Along the lines of  "While Completed Date is of a value that is on or between Last Monday-Today and If Due Date is before Last Monday, make Due Date Monday" - Any thoughts, I think it would be less code also

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, see my comments in code. Also, at this point, I think this question is more appropriate for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

```
finaldf['Completed_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Completed_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date

# making it lower case y made it work 
finaldf['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Due_Date'], format="%m/%d/%y").dt.date 

# this worked as of 4.16
current_week_flags = (finaldf.Completed_Date >= last_monday.date()) & (finaldf.Completed_Date <= today.date()) 
earlydue = (finaldf.Due_Date < last_monday.date())

flags = current_week_flags & earlydue
finaldfmon = finaldf[current_week_flags]

# here we make all the due dates before monday, monday while complete date filterered
# this works because last_monday is a single day
finaldfmon.loc[(finaldfmon['Due_Date']<last_monday.date()), 'Due_Date'] = last_monday 

# this fails in two places:
# finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date']), 'Due_Date'] = finaldfmon['Due_Date'] 

# finaldf['Due_Date'] != finaldfmon['Due_Date'] 
# these two series have different length, so you can't compare them 
# even if they have the same length, they have different indices
# (unless one of them is a single number/date, then it becomes the case above)

# finaldf.loc[..., 'Due_Date'] = finaldfmon['Due_Date']
# same story    

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('currentweek.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
finaldf.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
writer.save()
```

The Code Below ( mainly the last line achieves the goal

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd # added when using visual studio 
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
#read in excel file
finaldf = pd.read_excel("scrubcomplete.xlsx", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", dtype=object)
finaldf.columns = finaldf.columns.str.strip().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
#
today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())
day_of_week = today.dayofweek
last_monday = today - pd.to_timedelta(day_of_week, unit='d') 
#


if day_of_week !=0:
    finaldf['Completed_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Completed_Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date
    finaldf['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(finaldf['Due_Date'], format="%m/%d/%y").dt.date # making it lower case y made it work
    current_week_flags = (finaldf.Completed_Date >= last_monday.date()) & (finaldf.Completed_Date <= today.date())
    finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Completed_Date'] >= last_monday.date()) & (finaldf['Completed_Date'] <= today.date()) & (finaldf['Due_Date'] < last_monday.date()), 'Due_Date'] = last_monday
```

Comment: cannot thank you enough for your help, I pasted in the conditional logic that got me to where I wanted to go - advise if you have any concerns, or hopefully it could help you gain a different mindset on how to solve the problem ! :) I may reach out to you again lol , but for now this part of the script is in the books!

Comment: Exactly what I meant by "update the `flags`". Make it easier to read: `flags = current_week_flags & (finaldf['Complete_Date'] >= last_monday.date())` and then `finaldf.loc[flags ,'Due_Date'] = last_monday`. But glad it works.

Comment: I see, so now I am moving on to the next part, and this same old issue arose, and I think it is because some Due Dates are now timestamps?? - I input my code and error above

Comment: Yes, as I said before, remove all `dt.date()` and `date()`, except for this `today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())`.

Comment: apologies, apologies, I had mis read that comment thinking it mean otherwise

Comment: another question about the dates, if you care to help me further , but I understand if you have had enough lol. Having so much trouble with these darn dates in pandas

Comment: I can't tell from what you put there. Codes look broken. Again, try to post as a separate question. But before that, run your code line by line to isolate which line yields the error.

Comment: Ok I will lost when I get home. Not sure why it didn’t show up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756093/pandas-conditional-logic-with-date-objects